# Why is security group in Windows Active directory called security?

Tags: active-directory, security-groups

Do you know in any chance why Security group [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579255(v=ws.11).aspx) is called **security**? Is any property of AD object somehow hashed or something like that?

Comment: Because security groups are used to secure access to resources?

Comment: you can add the distribution group to any other resource in AD and modify the access level aswell...

Comment: Yes, but security groups in AD precede distribution groups in AD by several years, and the intent for security groups is to secure access to resources, hence the name. The intent of distribution groups isn't to secure access to resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security groups are intended to assign permissions on resources (file share, ...), while distribution groups should only be used for mailing lists.

The main difference, technically speaking, is that the Distribution Groups are NOT included in the security principal's token (a security principal is a computer, or a user for example), thus, you can't use a distribution group to secure a file share for example.

*Security groups => Assign permissions (=security related)*

more information here (for Windows 2000, but it's still valid): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960640.aspx